# python: How to use for loop in findall

Tags: python, regex, for-loop

I am trying to use for loop to re.findall() in jupyter notebook. 
I want to extract all the sentences that contains 'California', 'Colorado', and 'Florida'. 
I can just write these.

```
import re

f =open("C:/Users/uib57309/Desktop/test.txt",mode='rt')
lines = f.read()
f.close()

re.findall(r"([^.]*?California[^.]*\.)",lines)

re.findall(r"([^.]*?Colorado[^.]*\.)",lines)

re.findall(r"([^.]*?Florida[^.]*\.)",lines)
```

But how can I shorten my code with for loop?
I tried like these, but this seems to be wrong.

```
test_list = ['California', 'Colorado', 'Florida'] 

for i in test_list: 

     result = re.findall(r"([^.]*?i[^.]*\.)",lines)

print(result)
```

Comment: you don't need a loop. Use regex `|`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need a loop, just create a regex with `"|".join`

```
test_list = ['California', 'Colorado', 'Florida']
result = re.findall(r"([^.]*?{}[^.]*\.)".format("|".join(test_list)),lines)
```

and to make sure the words aren't sub-strings use word boundary (not really necessary with those particular words but for the general case it is. Then the expression uses one more wrapping with r`\b` characters:

```
r"([^.]*?{}[^.]*\.)".format("|".join([r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in test_list]))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop, result is finding all searches with the literal "i" string character.
Use the f-string (for 3.6+); string concatenation or formatting is okay too:

`result = re.findall(f"([^.]*?{i}[^.]*\.)", lines)   # works in Python 3.6+`

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to do it in a clean way, you must use NLTK to separate sentences. Your code relies on the assumption that a period always separates sentences, but, in general, that is not true.

```
import nltk
import re

lines = "Hello, California! Hello, e.g., Florida? Bye Massachusetts"

states = ['California', 'Colorado', 'Florida'] 

# Create a regex from the list of states
states_re = re.compile("|".join(states)) 

results = [sent for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(lines) \
           if states_re.search(sent)] # Check the condition
#['Hello, California!', 'Hello, e.g., Florida?']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use word boundary for this task and also make a list to store.

`result` variable will be overwritten with each iteration of loop.

```
test_list = ['California', 'Colorado', 'Florida'] 
x = []

for i in test_list: 
    pattern = r"\b"+i+r"\b"
    result = re.findall(pattern,lines)
    x.append(result)

print(x)
```